# Unable to load nib file: MainWindowController.xib, exiting

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I just created my first Mac Application but the program keeps crashing with this message:

`Unable to load nib file: MainWindowController.xib, exiting`

All I did was delete MainMenu.xib and created MainWindowController.xib and added it as the MainInterface.

[image]

Comment: check for typos? check the built bundle's contents and see what nib files are contained in the final product.

Comment: @BradAllred See my edit...I added a picture

Comment: that picture doesn't show what nibs are actually being packaged in your bundle...

Comment: @BradAllred How do I check whats actually bundled?

Comment: @BradAllred I am sorry but this is my first Mac Application

Comment: go to your build products directory and right click on the .app and and select "Show Package contents" and then look in the "Resources" directory.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41904/discussion-between-brad-allred-and-abdullah-shafique)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This error is caused by the nib/xib missing at runtime when `NSApplication` tries to load what it is told is the main interface nib. In most cases it stems from accidentally removing the nib from the "Copy Bundle Resources" build phase for your application target. For other (non main nibs) it can also be caused by typos when typing the nib name.

In this specific case, however, I have determined that selecting the "main interface" from the dropdown menu in the target properties section is bugged. You have to delete the ".xib" extension from it for it to work correctly; so manually type `MainWindowController` instead of the `MainWindowController.xib` that you selected.

With the ".xib" extension in the "Main Interface" box, `NSApplication` will erroneously attempt to load `MainWindowController.xib.xib`

Comment: The edit is what worked for me. Deleting the .xib extension from the "Main Interface" setting in the General tab in your Target for your app will solve the issue.

Comment: yes, Xcode 6.0.1 Once it started happening I had to use Clean (under the Product menu) then run it. Btw, my main interface settings were set correctly (i.e. changing it did not fix the problem for me as outlined above) Just FYI.

Comment: Same here as described by @JohnMorrison. From one minute to the other it complained it can't find my MainMenu.xib, even though the name was correct (w/o .xib) and Xcode even suggested it to use when clicking the dropdown in the target settings. The "Clean" in the "Product" menu fixed it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just cleaning and building again is what worked for me.

Comment: should be comment